# i have a macbook - 2012 and the ssd is full - only 32mb free - i cannot boot up . need to delete files but how?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, disk-utility, startup, ssd

My 2012 MacBook has a 240gb SSD, will not boot up.  I can get into disk utility, and it cannot verify disk or repair disk.  I can see that there is only 32mb free. I think this is the problem.

If I can free up some memory it may boot.  I'm a user but not an expert.  Help pls

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! In order to help you we're going to need more details. For starters, what exact model of MacBook do you own? I assume a MacBook Pro, but is it the 13" or 15" and is it the Mid-2012 or Late 2012 model, Retina or not? Also, do you happen to have access to another Mac? If so, what exact model?

Comment: You say that it can't verify or repair the disk. What errors is it telling you? The drive being full should not stop it verifying or repairing the disk. My guess is that there is another problem here.

Comment: If you can mount the disk, try removing the sleep images and swap files in `/var/vm`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, space is certainly an issue.

can you put this into target disk mode with a fireire or thunderbolt connection to another mac?  this is relatively user friendly if you have another mac around and a connection between them.

do you have a recovery partition on this machine?  is that how you got to disk utility without being able to boot?

you could boot into this and use terminal to remove some unneeded files to make it bootable/repairable.